# WAMP server can not open localhost and phpMyadmin

Tags: localhost, wamp

The icon is green.And my OS is windows 10.I just instal wamp today. And I did instal Visual C++ Redistributable before it.I change my port number to 8080.Everything seems ok ,what's the problem?

Here is my apache issue log

```
[Mon Feb 15 08:47:58.667573 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5396:tid 620] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 15 08:47:58.667573 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5396:tid 620] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Mon Feb 15 08:47:58.667573 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5396:tid 620] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Mon Feb 15 08:47:58.698614 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5396:tid 620] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6448
[Mon Feb 15 08:47:59.064992 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6448:tid 600] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: I followed instructions step by step .I tried other solutions provided in other questions. And it does not work.

Comment: you may try asking this question over on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I found the solution. May be it will help you, too.

Comment: try youtube tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer. I disable the IIS in port 80.And then ,I change my port back to 80.It works.
How to disable IIS in port 80. take this linkhttp://forums.iis.net/t/1227982.aspx?IIS+10+0+in+Windows+10+Pro